# Slang-Dictionary as downloadable text file?

Tags: resources

I am working with data from social media. I am currently looking for a (free?) web-speech2normal-speech dictionary. 
A dictionary that contains mapping likes

`ur -> you are`

Does anyone have any knowledge about such a freely available resource?